# Unable to run python manage.py runserver command even though django is installed

Tags: python, django

I am not able to run my local server through atom terminal, even though all the requirements are meant. This is the error i get when I run python manage.py runserver,

*File "manage.py", line 17
) from exc
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

I tried python3 manage.py runserver as suggested by some people online as a solution for mac users but it gave a different error,

*ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forge
t to activate a virtual environment?*

Sharing the screenshot of my atom terminal.

Comment: could you try to install django again using `pip3`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also installed django for python3.
By doing `pip -V` you can verify that your pip belongs to the python installation you expected.

You might need to use `pip3` if you're running python 2 and 3 in parallel. Alternatively, you can use `python3 -m pip install Django` to make sure it's for python 3

Comment: It actually worked. Just had upgrade my pip version to 20.3.3. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this problem occurs when you use the wrong python to runserver
that is, instead of using the python you used in installing your django you used another one